# Import-Csv include empty fields in end of row

Tags: powershell, import-csv

**Edit**

I'll conclude that Import-Csv is not ideal for incorrect formatted CSV and will use Get-Content and split. Thanks for all the answers.

Example CSV:

```
"SessionID","ObjectName","DatabaseName",,,,,,,,
"144","","AC"
```

Using `Import-Csv` none of the empty fields at the end will be counted - it will simply stop after "DatabaseName".

Is there any way to include the empty fields?

**Edit:**
I simply need to count the fields and make sure there are less than X amount of them. It is not only the header that might contain empty fields but also the content. These files are often manually made and not properly formatted. Since the files also can get very large, I would prefer to not also use `Get-Content` and split since I'm already using `Import-Csv` and its properties.

Comment: What would you do with untitled fields without value in the first place?

Comment: _"... manually made and not properly formatted..."_ - well there's your root problem.

Comment: import-csv was not designed to help you cope with csv files that are improperly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's missing its headers. If you would add some, it would work fine.

You could do something like

```
Get-Content My.CSV | Select -skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "SessionID","ObjectName","DatabaseName",'Whatnot1', 'Whatnot2', 'Whatnot3'
```

Comment: I'm using this to validate a CSV-file I have not created which also can include wildly different header names. The names themselves are not so important but I have to confirm that the amount of fields does not exceed a certain number - and empty fields at the end must also count as fields. The first line in the example is the header

Comment: So you would need to count the delimiters in the first line and are done?

Comment: Yes and no, I also need to do the count on each line (can be hundred of thousands). I already use Import-Csv to access properties so I would like to avoid also using Get-Content and splitting.

Comment: If its a properly formatted csv, there will not be more columns than headers. That's not true in youre case?

Comment: No, because the files can either be manually made or through excel and converted to csv, which can generate quite creative formats.

Answer (score 0):

As dbso suggested split and Length will help you. I was on the way to code a header routine which now is obsolete. Nevertheless here it is:

```
$FileIn = "Q:\test\2017-01\06\SO_41505840.csv"
$Header= (Get-Content $FileIn|select -first 1)-split(",")
"Fieldcount for $FileIn is $($Header.Length)"
for($i=0; $i -lt $Header.Length; $i++){if ($Header[$i] -eq ""){$Header[$i]="`"Column$($i+1)`""}}
$Header -Join(",")
```

Returning this output

```
Fieldcount for Q:\test\2017-01\06\SO_41505840.csv is 11
"SessionID","ObjectName","DatabaseName","Column4","Column5","Column6","Column7","Column8","Column9","Column10","Column11"
```